# Error on Admin login - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel

I have installed Magento 2.1 with PHP 7.0.11 on a nginx/PHP-FPM web server. When I go to my Magento Admin URL and login with my credentials, I receive an error -

"
**Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/etc/pki/tls/certs) is not within the allowed path**"

This appears to be an issue with Magento 2.1, as I have not come across this on my Magento 2.0 installations with the same server setup.

In order to fix the issue, I added `"/etc/pki/tls/certs"` to my open_basedir settings.

My questions are:

- Is this open_basedir error truly the problem, or is it being caused by
  something else?
- Is adding `"/etc/pki/tls/certs"` to my open_basedir    settings a
  security risk? It seems like an odd thing to add to    open_basedir.

Comment: probably too late but I have figured it out :)

Answer (score 11):

I just wasted a day on this and eventually figured out that NO, the certs are not the problem. Composer is the problem.

`/home/alpinewi/m2.alpinewines.co.uk/magento2/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php(801): Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getSystemCaRootBundlePath()`

I eventually went digging on the bug tracker of Magento 2 and found something! This is all caused by composer and the version of composer that 2.1.2 is tracking along, which is an alpha

Edit you composer.json file

find the line

`"composer/composer": "@alpha"`

change to

`"composer/composer": "1.1.2 as 1.0.0-beta1"`

now run

`composer update`

and you should see

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.0.6)
Downloading: 100%
- Removing composer/composer (1.0.0-beta1)
- Installing composer/composer (1.1.2)
Downloading: 100%
```

The ca-bundle is what fixes the error, I think. it was totally missing in the more recent alpha version

see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4359

Comment: obviously it is a little late for the original poster, but hopefully it can help the next person to encounter this

Comment: If you are coming to this now in 2017, there's probably a newer version number you can use than 1.1.2

Answer (score 8):

Put `disable-tls:true` in `composer.json` file, as in following :

```
"config": {
"use-include-path": true 
"disable-tls": true
},
```

this is because of ssl

[Source](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Install-2-1-0-Your-PHP-version-is-The-required-PHP-version-is/td-p/43400).

Comment: That will install Magento w/o TLS. You will loose transport security. This does not only affect the installation via composer but can also the Magento application itself.

Comment: Thanx Alam its save me lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Very late response, but this can be fixed by changing your server settings. In Plesk, if you go to PHP Settings just change `open_basedir` to "none".