# Fresh install can't login as admin

Tags: magento2, admin

Today I have installed Magento via the DirectAdmin installer.
 
The home page is working fine.

When I login as admin I get this error:

> Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/etc/pki/tls/certs) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/home/minergea/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php56/lib/php/)
>   in
>   /home/minergea/domains/minergear.eu/public_html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php
>   on line 914

How can I fix this?

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can take reference from here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137516/error-on-admin-login-magento-2-1

Comment: Can you try this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8021

Answer (score 0):

Edit you **composer.json** file

find the line

```
"composer/composer": "@alpha"
```

change to

```
"composer/composer": "1.1.2 as 1.0.0-beta1"
```

Put **disable-tls:true in composer.json** file, as in following :

```
"config": {
"use-include-path": true 
"disable-tls": true
},
```

now run

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't tested it bu try this:

1. rootProject/`composer.json` around **line 12**,

   change `"composer/composer": "@Alpha"` to `"composer/composer": "1.1.2 as 1.0.0-beta1"`
2. Run : `composer selfupdate`

Source : [GitHub Stabilize Composer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4359#issuecomment-225115951)